# Why would you cast a struct as a char* when using fread in c?

Tags: c

Lets say I have a "Passenger" struct, which has a field for a name.

If I do (like the syntax of my book shows):

```
fread(&passenger, sizeof(Passenger), 1, in_fp);
printf("%s", (*passenger).first_name)
```

I get a segmentation fault, but if I do:

```
fread( (char *)passenger, sizeof(Passenger), 1, in_fp);
printf("%s", (*passenger).first_name)
```

the name read from the file will be printed out.

Comment: Just a small style suggestion: `passenger->first_name` is the usual (and more readable) way to access structure fields though a pointer.  It's exactly equivalent to the expression you used - `(*passenger).first_name` - so this has nothing to do with your problem, it's just a more accepted style.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably have a pointer to a Passenger, not a Passenger:

```
fread(passenger, sizeof(Passenger), 1, in_fp); printf("%s", (*passenger).first_name)
```

Will most likely do what you want.

Comment: So, since I gave the address of "passenger" by calling it, I don't need the ampersand correct?

Comment: calling it with foo(&passenger)

Comment: Please look twice at the declaration of "passenger". It must be a pointer to Passenger, otherwise your code wouldn't even compile. So the value of the variable "passenger" is a pointer to the Passenger structure in question. The fread function wants a pointer to a buffer, where the data will be written. So the data is written to the Passenger in question. If you add an & operator to passenger, the data is written to the location where the passenger variable lives - probably somewhere on the stack, resulting in a STACKOVERFLOW.

Answer (score 8):

Looks to me as if 'passenger' is a pointer. If you take &passenger, you are passing the address of the pointer to fread. When you cast it, you are telling fread to treat it as a pointer to a char buffer instead of a pointer to a Passenger.

Comment: Well, Passenger passenger was declared in main, so I'm doing foo(&passenger)

Comment: That cannot be true, given the line of code (*passenger).first_name. It's a pointer.

Comment: Well, Passenger could be a typedef for `(struct passenger_struct *)` :)

Comment: Then the part that isn't true is "Lets say I have a 'Passenger' struct".

Comment: If `passenger` was a struct object (not a pointer), neither `(char *) passenger` nor `*passenger` would compile. `passenger` is a pointer in your code, there's no way around it.

Answer (score 3):

In the early days of C language, C had no `void *` type (it appeared later, was borrowed from C++ actually) and type `char *` was used as the generic "raw memory" pointer type instead. So, even to this day you might see this habitual rudimentary use of type `char *` as the generic pointer type in the code, and see other pointer types explicitly converted to and from `char *` in generic pointer context. I'd guess that the code you quoted does this for that specific reason. (Unless it was you who put this `char *` cast there. In that case I can only ask "Why?".)

In modern C the first parameter of `fread` has `void *` type, meaning that no cast is necessary. This

```
fread(passenger, sizeof *passenger, 1, in_fp);
```

whill work just as well.

Your `&passenger` version makes no sense, since apparently the original intent was to read data into the location `passenger` points to, not into the `passenger` pointer object itself.

Comment: Even using char* instead of void*, no cast would be necessary.

Comment: do you mind if I copy your historical disquisition into my answer to make it more complete?